# Database Schema Review

Tags: database-design, schema

I am working on a web app for an ESL institue. The app will be used only by the staff members (Not the students) to manage classes, payments, and student data.

I have gathered all of the data from the client, and according to the data I have came up with the following database schema.

[image]

I would be happy if someone takes a look and points out any flaws in the design or gives me recommendations to simplify it / make it more efficient.

Comment: Will you need to track lesson data as well, such as which material(s) where used, the goals of the lesson, participation scores, etc?

Comment: @matigo thanks for your comment. No, I don't need to store any of those.